# For which values of $x$ does $y$ have a value in $x^y=y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, upper-lower-bounds

For which values of $x$ does $y$ have a value in $x^y=y$? What are the lowest and highest values of $x$?
Using geogebra I have found that $x$ should be between $0$ and about $1.4$, but how is an exact answer found? Also, I am only talking about real numbers.
Thank you.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Have you found some $x$ that have such a $y$? (presumably you mean real numbers here, right?).  Have you found some $x$ that don't have such a $y$?

Comment: I’ve edited the question.

Comment: Hint: Your equation is equivalent to $x = y^{1/y}$.

Comment: I'm not sure how you get the maximal $x$ without using calculus.  Perhaps you were only meant to do it numerically?  It's easy with calculus, but you tagged pre-calculus here.

Comment: Your $1.4$ is a bit low but you are in the ball park.  I don't know how sensitive your algebra system is, but you should be able to get a more accurate value just by playing with it a bit.  If it serves as a hint, the answer is not something most people would recognize numerically.  It's not $\sqrt 2$ for example.

Comment: An alternative approach, that is similar to the approach of @Dan is that $\displaystyle ~\log(x) = g(y) = \frac{\log(y)}{y}.~$ Regardless of whether you interrogate $g(y)$, or interrogate $h(y) = y^{(1/y)}$, you have to choose a pertinent function to interrogate.  This means examining the derivative of the function, and detecting the complete range (i.e. co-domain) of the function.

Comment: In terms of the [Lambert $W$-function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.13), $y = \exp ( - W( - \log x))$ with $0 < x \le \exp (1/e) = 1.444667861 \ldots$.